# VHDL Code: Illegal type conversion converting std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl, type-conversion, multiplication

I am trying to be multiply the values in the line:

Q<= unsigned(reg_output) or (unsigned(multiplicand) and unsigned(shifted_lsb)*"0010");

note: I know multiplicand is a std_logic_vector, I did this for comparison via the if's.

Everytime I compile I get the error:
Illegal type conversion from ieee.std_logic_1164.STD_LOGIC to ieee.NUMERIC_STD.UNSIGNED (non-numeric to array).

here is my code below:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all; 
entity shiftaddr is
 port(
 clk, clear : in std_logic;
 multiplicand: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
 reg_output: in unsigned(7 downto 0);
 shifted_lsb: in std_logic;
 Q: out unsigned(7 downto 0) );
end shiftaddr;

architecture arch of shiftaddr is
 signal temp: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
begin

 shift: process(clk,clear,multiplicand, shifted_lsb,reg_output) --Define a process and state the inputs


begin

if (clk = '0') then
 Q <= reg_output;
end if;

if (clk = '1') then


    if (multiplicand(0) = '1') then Q <= (reg_output);
    end if;

    if (multiplicand(1) = '1') then 
    Q<= unsigned(reg_output) or (unsigned(multiplicand) and unsigned(shifted_lsb)*"0010");
    end if;
end if;

 end process;
end arch;
```

How do I go about fixing this? Thanks

Comment: Sorry I am not on computer for test so no answer. I believe the `unsigned(shifted_lsb)` is illegal since it is std_logic. You only can convert the std_logic_vector. With my understand of your code, this code `unsigned(shifted_lsb)*"0010"` doesn't need multiplier which cost expensively. Why you don't change to AND or using IF branch. It doesn't change the function for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from:

```
unsigned(shifted_lsb)*"0010"
```

`shifted_lsb` is not a vector, you cannot convert it to `unsigned` which is a vector type. As suggested by Khanh N. Dang you could just test its value instead.

But your code is probably bogus: your sensitivity list is not that of a synchronous process while one of your signals is named `clk`. Moreover, if you want your process to be a synchronous one you will have a problem because you are using both states of the clock. You should probably:

- indent your code so that we can read it without too much effort,
- think hardware first: if you have a clear idea of the hardware you want (registers, adders, multiplexers...), coding usually becomes very easy,
- read again the part of your text book about synchronous processes.